# how to set didSet on property of new object

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
class Bar: UIViewController {
  lazy var foo = Foo()

  foo.bar {
    didSet {
      barLabel.text = "\(foo.bar)"
    }
  }
```

however, I get an `expected declaration` error on `foo.bar`.  How would I resolve this error?

Comment: You can't add a `didSet` to an unrelated class like that. You're looking for something like the Observable pattern. I'd recommend you watch the WWDC 2019 video [Introducing Combine](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/722/) (even if you don't use Combine, this is conceptually similar to RxSwift, which is currently more accessible)

Answer (score 1):

`willSet`, `didSet`, `get` and `set` form part of a [variables *declaration*.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID359)

You declare your variable with:

`lazy var foo = Foo()`

Which also initialises the variable to an object instance of type `Foo`

To add a `didSet` you will need to change your declaration. One possible way would be:

```swift
    var foo: Foo = Foo() {
        didSet {
            barLabel.text = "\(foo.bar)"
        }
    }
```

But that will only fire when the variable `foo` is changed. If you want it to fire when the `bar` property of the `foo` variable changes you will need to add change the definition of `Foo`